# jQuery find items with each

Tags: jquery

I have multiple elements of the same class and I want to customize them, I can separate my input values, but I have no idea how to customize my span values.

```js
jQuery('.qty').each(function(){

    if( jQuery(this).val() == jQuery(this).attr("max") ){
        jQuery(this).find('plus').text("Max Value");
    }
    else if( jQuery(this).val() == jQuery(this).attr("min") ){
            jQuery(this).find('min').text("Min Value");
    }
});
```

```css
input{
  line-height:25px;
  width:150px;
  margin:10px 0;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  
   opacity: 1;
}
span{
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="minus"></span>
<input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="4">
<span class="plus"></span>
<br>
<span class="minus"></span>
<input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="2">
<span class="plus"></span>
<br>
<span class="minus"></span>
<input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="3">
<span class="plus"></span>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you create (at least) three jQuery instances of the same object for each `.qty` element? Store the result of `jQuery(this)` in a variable, or skip jQuery for this completely. `this.value`, `this.min`/`this.max` + `this.previousSiblingElement`/`this.nextSiblingElement` will do the job as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues in your code.

Firstly, you need to check the value of each `.qty` element when the user interacts with it, not on load of the page. To do this hook your logic to an `input` event handler.

From there you need to use `prev()` and `next()` to get the `span` elements as they are siblings to the `input`. `find()` is intended to search for child elements, so is not applicable in this case. You also need to include the `.` prefix on the classnames in your selectors.

Taking this a step further you can add an `else` clause to your `if` statement which removes the text labels when the min/max value is not selected.

Finally, the correct class for the first `span` in each set is `.minus`, not `.min`.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.qty').on('input', function() {
    let $el = $(this);    
    
    if ($el.val() == $el.attr("max")) {
      $el.next('.plus').text("Max Value");
    } else if ($el.val() == $el.attr("min")) {
      $el.prev('.minus').text("Min Value");
    } else {
      $el.next('.plus').text("");
      $el.prev('.minus').text("");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  line-height: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  opacity: 1;
}

span {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="minus"></span>
<input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="4">
<span class="plus"></span>

<br />

<span class="minus"></span>
<input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="2">
<span class="plus"></span>

<br />

<span class="minus"></span>
<input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="3">
<span class="plus"></span>
```

Also note that you can make your code far more succinct by alisasing `jQuery` within your document.ready handler, as I've done in the example above to give you access to the `$` variable again.

In addition it's good practice to 'cache' the jQuery objects, as accessing the DOM and building jQuery objects are (relatively) slow operations so you want to aim to do it as little as possible. In the example above you can see I accessed `$(this)` only once and stored its value in a variable within each event handler.

Answer (score 1):

With your current HTML, you'd use `prev` to get the `minus` span and `next` to get the `plus` span (but keep reading). You probably also want to clear the span when the condition isn't true, and update when the value changes:

```
function update() {
    jQuery('.qty').each(function() {
        const input = jQuery(this);
        const val = input.val();
        input.next().text(
            val == input.attr("max")
            ? "Max value"
            : ""
        );
        input.prev().text(
            val == input.attr("min")
            ? "Min value"
            : ""
        );
    });
}
update();
jQuery(".qty").on("input", update);
```

Live Example:

```js
function update() {
    jQuery('.qty').each(function() {
        const input = jQuery(this);
        const val = input.val();
        input.next().text(
            val == input.attr("max")
            ? "Max value"
            : ""
        );
        input.prev().text(
            val == input.attr("min")
            ? "Min value"
            : ""
        );
    });
}
update();
jQuery(".qty").on("input", update);
```

```css
input{
  line-height:25px;
  width:150px;
  margin:10px 0;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  
   opacity: 1;
}
span{
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="minus"></span>
<input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="4">
<span class="plus"></span>
<br>
<span class="minus"></span>
<input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="2">
<span class="plus"></span>
<br>
<span class="minus"></span>
<input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="3">
<span class="plus"></span>
```

But to me, that's fragile. I'd instead wrap each set of elements in a `div`, like this:

```html
<div>
    <span class="minus"></span>
    <input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="4">
    <span class="plus"></span>
</div>
```

...and then use `jQuery(this).closest("div").find(/*...*/)` to find the `plus` and `minus` elements:

```
function update() {
    jQuery('.qty').each(function() {
        const input = jQuery(this);
        const val = input.val();
        const div = input.closest("div");
        div.find(".plus").text(
            val == input.attr("max")
            ? "Max value"
            : ""
        );
        div.find(".minus").text(
            val == input.attr("min")
            ? "Min value"
            : ""
        );
    });
}
update();
jQuery(".qty").on("input", update);
```

(Note that I've looked for `.minus`, not `.min`, to find the `class="minus"` `span`.)

Live Example:

```js
function update() {
    jQuery('.qty').each(function() {
        const input = jQuery(this);
        const val = input.val();
        const div = input.closest("div");
        div.find(".plus").text(
            val == input.attr("max")
            ? "Max value"
            : ""
        );
        div.find(".minus").text(
            val == input.attr("min")
            ? "Min value"
            : ""
        );
    });
}
update();
jQuery(".qty").on("input", update);
```

```css
input{
  line-height:25px;
  width:150px;
  margin:10px 0;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  
   opacity: 1;
}
span{
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span class="minus"></span>
    <input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="4">
    <span class="plus"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="minus"></span>
    <input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="2">
    <span class="plus"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="minus"></span>
    <input type="number" class="qty" value="1" min="1" max="3">
    <span class="plus"></span>
</div>
```